# How to get all linked records from table

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a MS SQL server with table who is linked on itself

```
| Id| PreviousId|  Decription |
|---|:---------:|------------:|
| 1 | null      | Blah        |
| 2 | 1         | Blah        |
| 3 | 2         | Blah        |
```

And I need to get list of all records starting from `Id=3`.

My list should look like:

```cs
public class Record{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? PrevId {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
}
List<Record> records= new List<Record>();

/*Code to get all records*/

//Result
record[0] = Record(){Id=3,PrevId=2,Descr="Blah"} 
record[1] = Record(){Id=2,PrevId=1,Descr="Blah"} 
record[2] = Record(){Id=1,PrevId=null,Descr="Blah"}
```

Thank you!

EDIT1:
Sorry guys, but i didn't mentioned that ID are not in order. And there can be situation when, for example, record with ID=17 link to previous record with id =12

Comment: This assignment `record[0] = Record(){Id=3,PrevId=2,Descr="Blah"}` is incorrect

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: That is just a description of how the result should be

Comment: _I need to get list of all records starting from Id=3_ why the result contains records with id equals 1 and 2? Please, clarify your question

Comment: It sounds like you mean you want to order them by Id descending - `var results = records.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);`

Comment: I thought that he would like to retrieve the hierarchy. More like "Give me record id 3 and all its ancestors".

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need the record and its ancestors, also in sition when ID are not in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my answer to meet the requirements in getting the heirarchy.

Put this in your main function:

```
        var idList = GetList();

        //The complete heirarchy list
        var ancestorList = new List<Record>();

        //startId will determine the beginning Id of your query
        int? startId = 3;

        while (true)
        {

            if (startId != null)
            {
                ancestorList.Add(GetList()
                  .Where(m => m.Id == startId)
                  .FirstOrDefault());
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            startId = GetPreviousId((int)startId);
        }

        //this is just for checking the list of ids, this is unnecessary
        foreach (var item in ancestorList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Retrieving all the data:

```
public List<Record> GetList(){

     var records = new List<Record>();

     using(YourDBContext db = new YourDBContext())
     {
        records = db.records
         .Select(s=> new Record()
         {
           Id = s.Id,
           PrevId = s.PreviousId,
           Desc = s.Description,
         }).ToList();
     }

     return records;
}
```

Retrieving the previous Id:

```
    public static int? GetPreviousId(int startId)
    {
        return GetList()
               .Where(m => m.Id == startId)
               .Select(m => m.PrevId) 
               .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is OK when id are in order. Please see my Question, I added some edits. Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to retrieve all the data that has an Id of 3 and all the previous Id of 3?

Comment: No, i want to retrieve all records that ar linked together. For exemaple: Id=8 -> Id=6->Id=5->id=3 and so on

Comment: @SBarkovskis Kindly check, I edited it to meet that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DbContext is something like:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public MyDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}
   public DbSet<Record> Records {get; set;}
}
```

The code to retrieve records from table is:

```
var db = new MyDbContext(connectionString);
var records = db.Records.ToList();
```

or, if you want to use LINQ syntax:

```
var db = new MyDbContext(connectionString);
var recordsQuery = from record in db.Records
                   select record;
var records = recordsQuery.ToList();
```

Note: since question is pretty basic, I suggest you to have a look at EntityFramework documentation or courses (Julie Lerman courses and books are great, IMO).

Answer (score 0):

Assuimng your table is named `Record`, then in your model (context class) you should have property represetning table calles `Record` or `Records` (if you set pluralising names in your model). So, getting records from table is done via that property on which you can use normal LINQ methods, such as `Where`:

```
var result = dbContext.Records.Where(r => r.Id >= 3).ToList();
```

`ToList()` will cause query to execute.

EDIT: to filter based on `PreviousId`, then use:

```
var result = dbContext.Records.Where(r => r.PreviousId == 3).ToList();
```

Comment: It's ok when all id are in the order, but if if have record with ID=7 and PreviousId=3?